# Wcf sent notification to website

Tags: wcf, push-notification, polling

I am using .net4. I have created a web app which is doing polling every 30sec.
I have a wcf service which writes to database the desired data **which** comming from android clients. 
The polling that the web site do every 30sec is based upon data from android.
As optimization instead of polling i was thinking something like "google cloud messaging". I mead that the ideal implementation should be :

1. Android push data to my db.
2. Instantly when data inserted ok to my db, send "something" in order website ask database 
   for data

My app is finished, is working with out problems so far.
**The question:**
Is there any way to implement the ideal implementation above?
I have tried singalr and comet. But i have not find something that i could implement in my situation.
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found solution to my problem. I follow [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404662/SignalR-Group-Notifications). 
I used SingalR (which is great lib).